# How much time dilation are we experiencing here on Earth?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, earth, time-dilation, estimation

We experience time dilation from speed and gravity, but we are in more than just the Earth's gravity field, but also the sun's and the galaxy's gravity field and we are both spinning at 1,670 km/h, orbiting the sun at 107,000 km/h and orbiting the galactic center at 720,000 km/h (these numbers are from space.com). What I want to know is what is our total time dilation compared to an observer far outside the galaxy and at rest compared to the milky way center?

Comment: @BioPhysicist I see you added the homework tag, I guess presuming I am a lazy student. You could say that I am lazy because I could probably look up all the data needed and even look up the formula, but I am no student and it is not homework, but I can see how it would seem so.

Comment: Being a layperson myself, I could easily be missing something, but I can't see the acceleration in all the rotational and orbital speeds.  Assuming that gravitational and "straightforward" acceleration effects are as identical in nature as Einstein figured them to be (which has always been considered to be a little questionable, given the curvature of the objects whose presence defines the space between them), wouldn't you need to add something about your observer's time in relation to ours, or at least about their distance from us?  (I realize that would leave your question answering itself.)

Comment: @hansnordblad No, that isn't the case. Note that it is not the "homework-tag". I suggest reading the full description of the tag. I typically put this on any question asking for a specific calculation. It is not a personal tag; I don't claim to know anything about you.

Comment: Answering your own question's OK on this site:  My own rep's a little low to post my comment as an answer, but the site's very conventional, so check it out 1st if you use the info in it.  (Things like all particles being point-like, and the EP being sacred, are what I'm calling "conventional":  Objections to the EP are scattered around in Oxford Press's 2017 "The Philosophy of Cosmology".)